# Why Are There 2 Events In Some Azure Eventhub Records?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

sorry if this is a dumb question, but I cannot seem to find the answer:
I am using an external source to read in Audit Log events in Azure Eventhub. I am able to get the data flowing and working, but I see that there are messages with the records field that have 2 messages, but some records only have 1 message. For those records that have 2 json events in them, why is this the case? I see that they might be related.

What I mean is that some logs I will see for some:
category:NoninteractiveSignin:

```
records:[{..},{..}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Hub messages are binary, and opaque to Event Hubs.  It’s entirely up to the sender what’s in each one.

So you’ll need to ask whatever application creates the messages about that.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it is up to what is sending to Azure Eventhubs to format the data as the number of records in each EventHub result from source A will be different from source B?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to determine the format at which they get sent? Is it documented?

Comment: Hopefully, but you haven’t said what is generating the audit logs.

Comment: I am seeing this for some Audit and NonInteractiveSignIn Logs.